# Using numpy loadtext

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file containing 10 columns of numbers. What I would like to be able to do is to create a dictionary in which the first three numbers (of the 10 per line) of each row of the data can be used as a key to access two further numbers in columns 6 and 7 (in the same line). I have been trying to do this using the numpy.loadtext (in Python 2.7) function however I am running into difficulties with the dtype argument? Is this the correct approach or is there a simpler way, and if so, what is the correct way to lay out the function.

Many thanks and please let me know if any clarification is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given column-spaced the format of your data,

```
   1   0   0      617.09        0.00        9.38 l   0.0000E+00
   2   0   0     7169.00     6978.44       94.10 o   0.1913E-05
   3   0   0      366.08      371.91       14.06 o   0.6503E-03
   4   0   0     5948.04     5586.09       52.95 o   0.2804E-05
   5   0   0     3756.34     3944.63       50.69 o   0.6960E-05
 -11   1   0      147.27       93.02       23.25 o   0.1320E-02
 -10   1   0       -2.31        5.71        9.57 o   0.2533E-02
```

I think it would be easiest to just use Python string manipulation tools like `split` to parse the file:

```
def to_float(item):
    try:
        return float(item)
    except ValueError:
        return item

def formatter(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if not line.strip(): continue
        yield [to_float(item) for item in line.split()]

dct = {}
with open('data') as f:
    for row in formatter(f):
        dct[tuple(row[:3])] = row[5:7]

print(dct)
```

yields

```
{(-11.0, 1.0, 0.0): [23.25, 'o'], (4.0, 0.0, 0.0): [52.95, 'o'], (1.0, 0.0, 0.0): [9.38, 'l'], (-10.0, 1.0, 0.0): [9.57, 'o'], (3.0, 0.0, 0.0): [14.06, 'o'], (5.0, 0.0, 0.0): [50.69, 'o'], (2.0, 0.0, 0.0): [94.1, 'o']}
```

---

Original answer:

`genfromtxt` has a parameter `dtype`, which when set to `None` causes `genfromtxt` to try to guess the appropriate `dtype`:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.genfromtxt('data', dtype = None)
dct = {tuple(row[:3]):row[5:7] for row in arr}
```

For example, with `data` like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 5 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

`dct` gets set to

```
{(1, 2, 5): array([6, 7]), (1, 2, 4): array([6, 7]), (1, 2, 3): array([6, 7])}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works when I use test data as above. The problem its throwing up is that the index is invalid. I think it's because my data are not evenly spaced, are a mixture of integers and floats and also some contain a '-' negative sign before them. I tried using delimiter=None but this does not seem to help. Sorry if I'm just being naive

Comment: Maybe post a sample of your data and we'll be able to suggest a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, a complete example of the above (correct) answer might look like:

```
    import numpy as np  
    f = open("data.txt", 'wa')  
    f.write("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n")  
    f.write("1 2 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n")  
    f.write("1 2 5 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n")  
    f.close()  
    arr = np.genfromtxt("data.txt", dtype=None)  
    dct = {tuple(row[:3]):row[4:6] for row in arr}
```

Which would result in:

```
    {(1, 2, 3): array([5, 6]), (1, 2, 4): array([5, 6]), (1, 2, 5): array([5, 6])}
```

It may be apparent, but NB: you will overwrite dictionary entries when you have identical elements in the first three columns of more than one row.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works when I use test data as above. The problem its throwing up is that the index is invalid. I think it's because my data are not evenly spaced, are a mixture of integers and floats and also some contain a '-' negative sign before them. I tried using delimiter=None but this does not seem to help. Sorry if I'm just being naive